# Altering the CPSR Reserved bits

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers

Despite that I'm aware of the note below in all of the ARM references, I wanna know if there is any way to alter the reserved bits in CPSR? How can I change reserved bits to generate my desirable value?

Thank you in advance,

*Note
For compatibility with future ARM processors, do not alter the reserved bits of a Program Status Register. Use read-modify-write operations when changing the CPSR.*

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0311d/ch02s04s02.html

Comment: it is quite possible there are no flip flops behind those bits to store anything. what happened when you tried a msr cpsr, r0 or whatever register and didnt add any _stuff after cpsr?  then mrs r0,cpsr to read it back?  were you able to change those bits?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Now compare the ARM968 with [something more modern](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0344k/Beibijfb.html) - how much state is your "desirable value" going to corrupt when someone runs your code on a v7 core?

Comment: it is also quite possible that one or some of them have a broken feature that was not removed, that you shouldnt mess with.  That whole category of what to do with reserved bits thing, unless you have access to the sources you dont really know, I cant imagine you are so starved for storage that you cant spare a handful of bits in ram somewhere or find some other read-write register in a peripheral you are not using that you can grab a few bits from.   there is no guarantee that even if there is storage behind these bits they are passed around to other psrs like the known cpsr bits.

Comment: for the specific chip and version/stepping of that chip you are using, once you just try it and find it works, that doesnt mean future steppings of that chip will behave the same nor other chips from that vendor or other arm cores.  so if you really need this and it happens to appear to work (lots of testing will be needed for that to be true) dont port that code without that extra work.

Comment: Thanks all, maybe I'd better to clarify my actual goal! I'm gonna add some security features to the executable code in ARM architecture by modifying llc in llvm compiler in order to enforce CFI. I need an empty register to store my secrete encryption key there during the execution, i.e. no memory disclosure attack could reveal the key. I know that there are some registers like XMM in AMD64 SysV ABI, but I'm wondering if there is any in ARM arch too? If there is any, how can I use it or change its application? Any reference would be appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keywords from the document you have cited are:

> For compatibility with future ARM processors

This means that you cannot know which meaning these bits have in a specific CPU. You may have a CPU that is produced after this text has been written where one of the reserved bits has a special meaning.

If this special meaning is "perform CPU reset" you'll crash the CPU when trying to alter these bits!

For the CPUs that are currently on market I think "dwelch" is right: These bits are simply hard-wired to some value and cannot be altered.